# Как добавить элемент в список списков по индексу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки, python-3.5

```
x = 7
y = 3
# допустим это индекс списка
index_point = 0
# это индекс кортежа
index = 0
points = [[(1,2),(2,2)], [(0,2),(2,0)]]

# Хотел через .insert попробовать,но увы
points.insert(([index_point], [index], (x, y)))
Ответ:
points = [[(7,3),(2,2)], [(0,2),(2,0)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 7
y = 6
points = [[(1,2),(2,2)], [(0,2),(2,0)], [(3,0),(3, 3)]]
index_point_area = 1
index_point = 1

# все было куда проще
points[index_point_area][index_point] = (x, y)
print(points)
```